# How to preform search in windowsform textbox

Tags: c#, search

I have created a windows form which has 4 groupboxes and each groupbox have multiple texts in it. I'm trying to create a custom search box/find box to find if a searched keyword exists in any of these groupboxes.

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

But I do not know how to search for a text inside groupbox. Could anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string keyword = "somekeyword";
keyword = keyword.ToLower();

List<GroupBox> lst = new List<GroupBox>();
lst.Add(groupBox1);
lst.Add(groupBox2);
lst.Add(groupBox3);
lst.Add(groupBox4);

foreach(var gb in lst)
{
    foreach(Control c in gb.Controls)
    {
        if(c is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)c;
            if(tb.Text!=null)
            {
                if(tb.Text.ToLower().Contains(keyword))
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```